# How to make a part of an object with navmesh agent rotate separately?

Tags: unity, navmesh

I have a game object (a Humvee jeep) and it has a turret gun on top of it.

What i want to do is while the vehicle is moving in a line the turret look at player. I tried rotating the turret gun with "Transform.rotation" and "transform.lookat()" but nothing happened.
Is it possible to move/rotate some part of an object with navmesh separately?